# get the second last line from shell pipeline

Tags: shell

I want to get the second last line from the `ls -l` output.
I know that 
`ls -l|tail -n 2| head -n 1` 
can do this, just wondering if `sed` can do this in just one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls -l|sed -n 'x;$p'
```

It can't do third to last though, because sed only has 1 hold space, so can only remember one older line. And since it processes the lines one at a time, it does not know the line will be next to last when processing it. awk could return thrid to last, because you can have arbitrary number of variables there, but the script would be much longer than the `tail -n X|head -n 1`.

Answer (score 1):

In a awk one-liner :

```
echo -e "aaa\nbbb\nccc\nddd" | awk '{v[c++]=$0}END{print v[c-2]}'
ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to delete second-last line in file

```
sed -e '$!{h;d;}' -e x filename
```

Comment: Why do you delete the pattern space for each line instead of just suppressing the printing with `-n`?

Answer (score 0):

```
tac filename | sed -n 2p
```

-- but involves a pipe, too