# Print the last 2nd line of a file in linux

Tags: linux, shell

how to print the last 2nd line of a text file in Linux, i can able to print the first 2nd line of a file using 'sed -n 2p'. in a same kind of way i want to print the last 2nd line . Its a log file we don't know the count. tail -n 1 will give the last line , but i want to print only the last 2nd line. please suggest

Comment: possible duplicate of [get the second last line from shell pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321955/get-the-second-last-line-from-shell-pipeline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `tail -n 2 file.txt | head -1`

Comment: Cool , this is what i want